# Excel logic with IF statements

Tags: excel, if-statement, logic

I made 75% of this logic already, I just need help for the last part.

here is the logic=

```
 =IF(AND(OR(G3=31,G3="31"),(TODAY()-60)>F3),"update to 32/40",IF(AND(SUM(H3:J3)=0,OR(G3=32,G3="32"),(TODAY()-105)>F3),"update to 33","no action"))
```

this basically says:

1. If G3 is 31 AND if its 60 days past the date in F3 then I want it to display "update to 32/40"
2. if G3 is 32 and the values in H3:J3 equals 0 and its 105 days past the date in F3 then i want it to say "Update to 33"

The logic i need to enter into this equation is

***if G3 is 31 and H3:J3 equals 0 and if its 105 days the past in f3 then i also want the result to display "update to 33"***

Thanks so much for your help :D

Comment: in bold you state G3=31 but in point 2 it is G3=32.  Was this a typo?  Secondly is it if it is 105 days past or 105 or more days past.  The potential problem with the SUM(H3:J3)= 0 is if H3 is -1 and J3 is 1 and the rest are 0, then your sum would be 0 but all the cells are NOT 0.

Comment: I think you're missing a closing `)` for your first `AND()` statement too...I guess after the `TODAY()`: ` =IF(AND(OR(G3=31,G3="31"),(TODAY()-60)>F3))...,` Same with the second

Comment: Instead of using `OR(G3=31,G3="31")`, you can use `VALUE(G3)=31`.

Comment: As @ForwardEd said, there's a problem in the second part where one value might net off another. To overcome that, you can add an additional argument in the `AND` function: `MIN(H3:J3)=0`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this formula.

```
=INDEX({"no action","update to 32","update to 33"},IF(TODAY()-F3>105, IF(AND(G3=31, SUM(H3:J3)<>0), 2,3), IF(TODAY()-F3>60, 2,1)))
```

First, to understand this perhaps unconventional approach, consider the INDEX function, like, `INDEX({"no action","update to 32","update to 33"},1)`. The 3 choices are numbered from 1 to 3. In the above formula the nested IF conditions therefore all evaluate to a number between 1 and 3 which just shortens the formula but doesn't detract from its complexity.

I resolved the impasse where you got stuck by defining when choice 2 should be displayed instead of choice 3 whenever the date is more than 105 days passed, in fact a reversal of what you described. Logical reversals of this type are tricky. I hope I got it right. :-)